# What's wrong with asking the advantages of Language A over Language B?

Tags: discussion, questions, low-quality-posts

I asked a question that within 5 minutes received 1 up vote and 7 down votes.

What was so bad about this question? I wanted to get the argument for Python, so I could see the other side of the story. Was it just the wording, or is something else terribly wrong? (no, there were no comments in the first 5 minutes before I deleted the question.)

> #### [What makes Python better than Node.JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686648/what-makes-python-better-than-node-js)
>
> So I do a Google search [Python vs
>   Node.JS](http://www.google.com/search?q=Python+vs+Node.JS), and I
>   found [a good
>   summary](http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-benefits-of-developing-in-node-js-versus-Python)
>   of what makes Node.JS better:
>
> > 1. It's built to handle asynchronous I/O from the ground up. Other environments have async. I/O features, but Node's the first
> >        environment where it's really pervasive. In most environments you'll
> >        find only limited pieces available in async. flavors, but in Node
> >        everything (or nearly everything) is async.-only.
> >
> >    ...
> > 2. It's "just JavaScript." ... Staying in a single language feels faster.
> > 3. It's new, so it has the benefit of being able to learn from previous languages' and environments' mistakes ... hasn't had time to
> >        accumulate the cruft other languages/environments have.
>
> I already use and like Node.JS, but I wanted to get a comparison that
>   is biased towards Python. What upsides would there be to introducing
>   Python into a team that is currently unfamiliar?
>
> I'm thinking
>
> - More widespread support
> - Less code to write for many operations
> - More complete library
>
> When it comes to a Web Development, is there anything else I should
>   know?

P.S. I love the streaming updates of my question score. :) Though I would suggest that we encourage more commenting during a rain of down-votes.

Comment: From the title "What makes A better than B" is one of those questions which sound pretty much "Not Constructive". The question itself seems to invite a discussion as well, which is not really what SO is for. That might have invited the downvotes.

Comment: Maybe something like, "please summarize the argument for Python over Node.JS"? or is this question just not going to fly?

Comment: No matter how well intended and how much you try to restrict the question from evolving into a discussion, it is very likely going to end up being one. It's one of those situations where, no matter how good you make your question, it's difficult to have it fit in with this particular Q&A IMHO.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/128562#128562

Comment: +1 for being _polite_ and _curious_. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> When it comes to a Web Development, is there anything else I should know?

This makes the question open-ended and a "list of" question which is not constructive/not a real question. There's a whole load of stuff you should know, but having a list of this stuff doesn't make the internet a better place and there's no one *thing* that you particularly need to know more than any other thing.

Answer (score 4):

[This Stackoverflow Blog Post by Jeff Atwood](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) helps break it down where I can understand.

If I understand correctly, my question was not specific enough, and too much akin to "tables vs divs" or "to semicolon or not to semicolon".

Although the question in question is more credible, there are still a lot of variables/details making one language different from the other, and a constructive question would need to be much more specific.